# Separate a group of values in to A or B (1 or 2) SQL

Tags: sql-server

Note: I have already asked a similar question but had omitted a key part in the fact that a tool has many components.

I have a list of multiple tools and their components that all have a model number. I want to group every second tool based on the model it belongs to.

The derivedColumn is the query I want to return

```
declare @t table (Model int, toolID INT ,Component INT,DerivedColumn int);
insert into @t values (1,1,1,1),(1,1,2,1),(1,1,3,1),(1,2,1,2),(1,2,2,2),(1,2,3,2),(1,3,1,1),(1,3,2,1),(1,3,3,1),(1,4,1,2),(1,4,2,2),(1,4,3,2),(1,5,1,1),(1,5,2,1),(1,5,3,1),(2,1,1,1),(2,1,2,1),(2,2,1,2),(2,2,2,2),(2,3,1,1),(2,3,2,1)


SELECT * FROM @t

Model   toolID  Component   DerivedColumn
1       1       1           1
1       1       2           1
1       1       3           1
1       2       1           2
1       2       2           2
1       2       3           2
1       3       1           1
1       3       2           1
1       3       3           1
1       4       1           2
1       4       2           2
1       4       3           2
1       5       1           1
1       5       2           1
1       5       3           1
2       1       1           1
2       1       2           1
2       2       1           2
2       2       2           2
2       3       1           1
2       3       2           1
```

Every second tool belonging to a model should have an alternative group number.

I believe I have to use a windows function but haven't been able to solve.

Comment: You can write query similar to the previous question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `dense_rank()` and `mod function %2` to calculate

```
DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE
(
   Model int, 
   ToolId int,
   Component int
)

INSERT INTO @SampleData
(
   Model, ToolId, Component
)
VALUES
(1, 1, 1),(1, 1, 2),(1, 1, 3),(1, 2, 1),
(1, 2, 2),(1, 2, 3),(1, 3, 1),(1, 3, 2),
(1, 3, 3),(1, 4, 1),(1, 4, 2),(1, 4, 3),
(1, 5, 1),(1, 5, 2),(1, 5, 3),(2, 1, 1),
(2, 1, 2),(2, 2, 1),(2, 2, 2),(2, 3, 1),
(2, 3, 2)

SELECT *,
     CASE (dense_rank() OVER(PARTITION BY sd.Model ORDER BY sd.ToolId) + 1) % 2
         WHEN 1 THEN 2
         WHEN 0 THEN 1
     END as  DerivedColumn
FROM @SampleData sd
ORDER BY sd.Model, sd.ToolId
```

Demo link: http://rextester.com/LIQL79881

Answer (score 0):

Hope it may helps you

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Model INT, toolID INT ,Component INT,DerivedColumn INT);
INSERT INTO @T VALUES (1,1,1,1),(1,1,2,1),(1,1,3,1),(1,2,1,2),(1,2,2,2),(1,2,3,2),(1,3,1,1),(1,3,2,1),(1,3,3,1),(1,4,1,2),(1,4,2,2),(1,4,3,2),(1,5,1,1),(1,5,2,1),(1,5,3,1),(2,1,1,1),(2,1,2,1),(2,2,1,2),(2,2,2,2),(2,3,1,1),(2,3,2,1)

SELECT Model
      ,toolID
      ,ROW_NUMBER()Over(Partition by toolID order by Model) AS AlternativetoolID
      ,Component
      ,DerivedColumn
from @t;
```